# How to call a object method without object instance?

Tags: javascript

I have a method loadSet which creates elements with datas from the localstorage, and this should be run on page load i am calling it via

> ReminderSet.prototype.loadSet(); // works fine

My question is, is there any other way to call a method that don't need a reference to an object instance? like `person1.loadSet();`  or should i abandon this and make it as a regular function?

```
ReminderSet.prototype.loadSet = function() {
    var keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = 0,
        key,
        array;

    for (; key = keys[i]; i++) {
        const setId = localStorage.getItem(key);
        array = JSON.parse(setId); //parse and store key values
        let array_index = 0;
        //Re-create the reminders and set their properties//
        $reminderSection.append($('<div/>').addClass('set').attr('id', key) //Set the ID                      
            .append($('<div/>').addClass('set-title').append($('<h1>').attr('contenteditable', 'true').text(array[array_index].set_title)), //Index is always at 0//
                $('<div/>').addClass('create-reminder-control').append($('<button>').addClass('add-new-reminder').text("+ add new"), $('<input>').addClass('create-reminder-value').attr({ type: "text", placeholder: "get something done" })), $('<div/>').addClass('reminder-lists'), $('<div/>').addClass('save-control').append($('<button>').addClass('save-reminder-button').text('Save'))))

        //Get our key values //
        for (; array_index < array.length; array_index++) {
            /*Select the element id */
            $("#" + key).children('.reminder-lists').append($('<div/>').addClass('a-reminder').attr('contenteditable', 'true').text(array[array_index].description).append($('<div/>').addClass('delete-reminder').text('x'))) //Get the reminders
        } //end

    }
};
```

Comment: If you need to call it without an instance, it probably shouldn't be an instance method. Define it on the object directly, not its prototype. That's basically a "static" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `loadSet` doesn't need or use an instance, it doesn't make any sense for it to be on `ReminderSet.prototype`. Either make it a standalone function:

```
function loadSet() {
    // ...
}
// Call it like so:  loadSet();
```

...or a property on `ReminderSet` itself:

```
ReminderSet.loadSet = function() {
    // ...
};
// Call it like so:  ReminderSet.loadSet();
```

Only put functions on the object that a constructor's `prototype` property refers to if they need to use `this` (the instance).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the function directly as a property of the other `ReminderSet`:

```
ReminderSet.loadSet = function() {//etc.}
```

Then you can simply call: `ReminderSet.loadSet()`